# How to add reviews from Facebook to Google

Tags: google-search, facebook, structured-data, user-reviews

I have a website which I created with WordPress.

I want to know how to add reviews from Facebook in Google search.

Also I want to know is there any way to show recent posts using Google business.

Is it possible using schema.org or Google Business?